# Remove Google Maps Account History

Tags: ios, privacy, google-maps

I have a simple question regarding **Google Maps**. I am **not** signed in with Google, and don't use their services anymore, yet, when I start Google Maps I get the following:

[image]

How can I completely eliminate that account that Google shows me?

Comment: Have you tried deleting that account on Google's side?  Are you signed into this Google account from **any** app or browser on your device?  Have you removed that account from iOS's Settings?

Comment: Also, have you tried to delete Google Maps and reinstall it again?

Comment: Of course I’ve tried the obvious, and GMaps is the only Google app on the phone. Not only that, but I never use social logins, so no Google/Facebook for me, I use email sign ups. Apps, however, when removed do not carry with them their payloads such as previous preferences. I see that with GMaps, but also Spotify does this: when reinstalling it finds the old login preferences.